# Filtering a sql server view with the outcome of another sql server view in Rstudio

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I am trying to use views on a sql server in Rstudio. I have a view that creates IDs that I need the other views to be filtered with but I keep getting errors and think I am not understanding the use of sql server views or something. I hope someone can help me with this.

This is the Rscript I am using

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(rstudioapi)

NameofIDscript <- "A"
server <- "sql-prd.database.windows.net"
database <- "Database"

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
             UID = askForPassword("username"),
             Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
             Server = server, Database = database,
             Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive")
```

After this I get the prompt for two factor authentication and this works fine

```
IDs <- dbGetQuery(conn = con, 
             statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM ", paste0("COHORT_", toupper(NameofIDscript))))$IDnumber
```

IDs get saved in vector IDs, this works fine

```
FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con,
      statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN (", paste0(IDs, collapse = ","), ")"))
```

paste0("SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN (", paste0(IDs, collapse = ","), ")") gets me the sql query I want. But when I run this it gives the error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:XXXX: XXXXX: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'PK010200001' to data type int.
```

For this specific table I know the number of rows I would expect. That is 3741. The following code does work and I don't know why it does when I fill in the exact number of rows or less. I cannot know the expected number of rows for all my tables. When I fill in 3742 it gives the same error as before.

```
FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con,
      statement = paste0("SELECT TOP (3741) * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN (", paste0(IDs, collapse = ","), ")"))
```

Can I fix this and if not, is there another way to fetch the data to R from the SQL server while using another view to filter the data

Comment: First, you may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front: don't `paste` data into a query, it's really bad practice. I'll first address the immediate fixes to your code ignoring this, then I'll suggest a safer path.

---

You are including string literals without any quotes. For instance, see

```r
paste0(iris$Species[1:3], collapse=",")
# [1] "setosa,setosa,setosa"
```

To a SQL database, those are tokens, not strings. Strings are identified using single quotes. The literal change (but please consider the rest of this answer) should be

```r
paste0(sQuote(iris$Species[1:3], FALSE), collapse=",")
# [1] "'setosa','setosa','setosa'"
```

You are probably safe using `sQuote(.., FALSE)`, but the "best" way (for reasons that may not really apply here) is to use `DBI::dbQuoteString`, so you could also use

```r
paste0(dbQuoteString(con, iris$Species[1:3]), collapse=",")
```

For your full code,

and for your code

```r
FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con,
      statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN (",
        paste(dbQuoteString(con, IDs), collapse=","),
        ")"))
```

---

Having said that, pasting data into queries is a bad idea for several reasons. While "SQL Injection" typically entails malevolent/intentional action, the effect can also be had with unicode strings, strings that include single/double quotes, etc. While malevolent injection can break queries and, if crafted well, can do harm to data in the database, when it is accidental it typically just causes the query to fail ... but it should still be guarded against. (There are other reasons to use parameter binding as I'm suggesting, but I don't think they will have a big effect on your use.)

To do this, we need a marker in the query to indicate where each datum goes. This varies by DBMS, but for SQL Server (and ODBC in general) it is `?`. That means that a query would look something like:

```sql
SELECT field1, field2, field3, id
FROM mytable
WHERE id in (?,?,?)
```

and then we include a list (length 3) with the `dbGetQuery`.

(Note that we cannot bind table names ... unfortunate.)

For you, I suggest this query:

```r
### having already retrieved IDs
qmarks <- paste(rep("?", length(IDs)), collapse = ",")
qry <- paste("SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN (",
             qmarks, ")")
FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con, qry, params = IDs)
```

See [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) for a good reference on doing queries safely (including this).

### UPDATE

When the vector/list of parameters gets extremely long, there are two ways to work around this.

1. If you don't need to download `IDs`, just to get their data, then you can nest the first query into the second, something like:

   ```r
   qry <- sprintf("
     SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE ID IN
       (SELECT * FROM %s)",
     paste0("COHORT_", toupper(NameofIDscript)))
   FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con, qry, params = IDs)
   ```

   (My choice to use `sprintf` is mostly to make it easier to see the underlying string template, this can be done using `paste` as well.)
2. Similarly, you can use a join, no nesting.

   ```r
   qry <- sprintf("
     SELECT ft.* FROM FIRST_TABLE ft
       INNER JOIN %s tb ON ft.ID = tb.IDnumber",
     paste0("COHORT_", toupper(NameofIDscript)))
   FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con, qry, params = IDs)
   ```
3. If you need `IDs` locally as well, you can still use the above and use

   ```r
   IDs <- unique(FirstFilteredTable$ID)
   ```

   Though technically if you find an ID in the first query that is not in `FIRST_TABLE`, it will not be present here.
4. Finally, if you need to download `IDs` locally before querying `FIRST_TABLE`, I think the best way is to upload the IDs you need into a temporary table and then use one of the queries from #1 or #2 above. For instance,

   ```r
   dbWriteTable(con, "#mytemp", data.frame(ID = IDs),
                create=TRUE, append=FALSE)
   qry <- "
     SELECT ft.* FROM FIRST_TABLE ft
       INNER JOIN #mytemp tb ON ft.ID = tb.IDnumber"
   FirstFilteredTable <- dbGetQuery(conn = con, qry, params = IDs)
   dbExecute(con, "drop table #mytemp")
   ```

   The leading `#` is specific to SQL Server, it is generally not helpful and can be invalid for other database servers, and for those one would need to do `dbWriteTable(..., temporary=TRUE)`. Technically, a temporary table does not *need* to be deleted, since it will be auto-deleted when you close your connection, but ... if you do this process repeatedly and use the same temp table name, then you may have problems. Unless you suspect you'll need the uploaded data for multiple queries like above, I suggest getting into the habit of deleting it intentionally as above.

Comment: Thank you very much. And also for introducing me to SQL Injection. The first solution you provided helps with the error I had, thanks a lot! But the more desired second option does not work for me becaus I get the error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error. Apparently because the server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Is there a way to still do it this way?

Comment: See my update @Cornelieke, there are a few options for dealing with "a lot" of parameters like that. The last (inserting to a new temporary table) works very well when you need to join against multiple fields, this is not as efficient using the other methods.